# How to convert SQL script to tableau filter?

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I have SQL script as below:

```
select name, location, max(trans_date)
From dataset
group by name, location
```

I want to replicate this in tableau using data source filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a calculated field with this formula:

```
[trans_date]={FIXED [name],[location]:MAX([trans_date])}
```

Set it to True in the data source filters